# asp Button Not firing JavaScript client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events, aspbutton

This is killing me has to be something simple I am overlooking. I am trying to fire off a simple JavaScript function from the click of an ASP button. My button looks like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFinalize" runat="server" Enabled="False" OnClientClick="finalizeClick(); return false;" Text="Finalize Selection" />
```

I do enable it based on some other client logic, once enabled I click it but nothing happens.

I have a break point inside the JS function `finalizeClick()` it never gets there.

So I tried a regular HTML button and it calls the function just fine and performs as expected. It looks like:

```
<input  type="button" id="btnFinalizeNotASP" value="button" onclick="finalizeClick();"/>
```

Going crazy, please help.

EDIT More info. Has to be something with `Enabled="False"`. If I take that out of the ASP tag it works. I want to start with the button disabled and enable it on other events client side I do that in another JavaScript event where I set:

```
finalizeButton.disabled = false;
```

Not sure why but `finalizeButton.enabled = true;` never turned the button on.

Still puzzled,

Comment: What if you try something like OnClientClick="javascript:finalizeClick();"

Comment: @Gabbar Thanks but still no love

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out something that works, but I don't really like it. Would like to know from others why and if there is a better solution.

If I leave the:

```
Enabled="False"
```

out of my ASP tag and put

```
var btnfinalize = document.getElementById("<%=btnFinalize.ClientID %>");
btnfinalize.disabled = true;
```

in the javascript of my page the ASP button is enabled during design, disabled when the page loads and properly fires the javascrip function I want when later enabled (really disabled=false ) and clicked

Answer (score 0):

Nope, You use HTML controls when you don't need the control to run on the server-side, not ASP.NET server controls.

i.e.

```
< input type="button" / >
```

instead of

```
< asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" / >
```

Comment: But I want to have some server side "stuff" happen after I have the user answer a continue/cancel question in my javascript function call